# Issue with Spring 4 + Jersey 2.8 + Spock combination

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, spock

I'm having really tough time getting Spring 4 + Jersey 2.8 + Spock test working together. I'm trying to a write a Spock unit test for Jersey REST service wired through Spring.

I'm annotating my Spock test using [spock-spring-0.7-groovy-2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring) annotations as shown below.

TestAppConfig is my Spring 4 configuration file. For some reason, instead of using this Java Spring configuration class, it is looking applictionContext.xml in the classpath. Stacktrace can be found below.

What am I missing here? Has anyone got this combination working?

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestAppConfig.class])
class WebServiceTest extends Specification {
    @Shared protected HttpServer server
    @Shared protected WebTarget target

    void setupSpec() {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(["org.myapp.webservice.rest.controller"])
                .property("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext")

        server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:"), rc)
        server.start();

        def config = new ClientConfig()
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient(config)
        target = c.target(baseUri);
    }

    void cleanupSpec() {
        server?.shutdownNow()
    }

    def "Query all clients"(){
        when: String responseMsg = target.path("/clients").request().get(String.class) 
        then: responseMsg != null
    }
}
```

This is my Jersey resource class

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class ClientHierarchyResource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientHierarchyResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private IClientHierarchyService clientHierarchyService;
    ...
}
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
20:14:26.112 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org.myapp.    application.common.springconfig.TestAppConfig]

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [    applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be     opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I changed the ResourceConfig configuration as following and now I'm getting a different error. `final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(PACKAGES).property("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext());` Here is the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@70c7e52b has not been refreshed yet`

Comment: Got it working. `final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(PACKAGES).property("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestAppConfig.class))`

Comment: Can you please create an answer for this advising exactly what you did so that others that experience the same issue can utilise it? Also don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working after fixing the ResourceConfig configuration.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestAppConfig.class])
class WebServiceTest extends Specification {
    @Shared protected HttpServer server
    @Shared protected WebTarget target

    void setupSpec() {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(PACKAGES).property("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestAppConfig.class))

        server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:"), rc)
        server.start();

        def config = new ClientConfig()
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient(config)
        target = c.target(baseUri);
    }

    void cleanupSpec() {
        server?.shutdownNow()
    }

    def "Query all clients"(){
        when: String responseMsg = target.path("/clients").request().get(String.class) 
        then: responseMsg != null
    }
}
```